# Browser cannot find servlet url after adding paramters, 500 cannot find questionpage?result=

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Before I was using `$.get("QuestionPage"...` with no parameters and everything was fine. I changed it to:

```
$.get("QuestionPage",{result:"nailed"},function(responseJSON){

           //set the question and category texts
           $("#cardArea").val(responseJSON["card"]);
           $( "#cat"  ).text(responseJSON["category"]);
           $( "#cardid" ).text(responseJSON["flashCardnum"]);

           //clear answer field after every 'next'...
           $( "#answerArea" ).val("");

           //set the click function of show button to show the answer..
           $( "#show" ).click(function() {
                $( "#answerArea" ).val(responseJSON["answer"]); 
                answerShown = true;
            });
       });
```

and now I get a 500 error cannot load resource. Here is part of the servlet method:

```
@WebServlet("/QuestionPage")
public class QuestionPageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Map<String,UserAccount> activeUsers;
    private List<Card> usersUpdatedCards = new ArrayList<>();  

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Comment: 404 would mean "cannot find". 500 means internal server error. your servlet throws exception. Check the stacktrace

Comment: It turned out that on the server side I was requesting a parameter that had not been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're forgetting the [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) variable in your ajax request.

```
$.get("../QuestionPage", $.param({result:"nailed"}), function(responseJSON) {
```